# Uploading the content of a variable as a file into FTP server using Bash

Tags: bash, curl, ftp

Using Bash scripting, I'm trying to upload the content of variable into an FTP server.

The variable is $HASHED and it contains some hashed password

> echo $HASHED

The output of the above command is: `M0eSl8NR40wH`

I need to do the following:

1. Create a time/date stamped file in the FTP server (i.e. PASSWORD_18_02_2014)
2. The file needs to have the same content of the $HASHED value (i.e. the PASSWORD_18_02_2014 needs to have M0eSl8NR40wH inside it).

Trying Curl, I couldn't get it working using the following:

```
UPLOAD="curl -T $HASHED ftp://192.168.0.1/passwords/ --user username:password"
$UPLOAD
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you (tested on Linux Mint 13):

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=PASSWORD_`date +%d_%m_%Y`
echo $HASHED >$FILENAME
ftp -n your_ftp_site <<EOF
user your_user_name_on_the_ftp_server
put $FILENAME
EOF
rm $FILENAME
```

A few caveats:

- You have to export HASHED, e.g. when you set it, set it like this: `export HASHED=M0eSl8NR40wH`
- The above assumes you will be running this from a terminal and can type in your password when prompted
- You may have to add some cd commands after the line that starts "user" and before the line that starts "put", depending on where you want to put the file on your ftp server

Don't forget to make the script executable:

```
chmod u+x your_command_script_name
```

You can code the password after the user name on the line that starts "user", but this leaves a big risk that someone can discover your password on the ftp server. At the very least, make the bash command script readable only by you:

```
chmod 700 your_command_script_name
```

Comment: Thanks Lencho. I will try it tomorrow and get back to me you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
HASHED="M0eSl8NR40wH"
echo "$HASHED" | curl --silent --show-error --upload-file \
-ftp://192.168.0.1/passwords/$(date +PASSWORD_%d_%m_%Y) --user username:password
```

Where:

```
--silent        : prevents the progress bar
--show-error    : shows errors if any
--upload-file - : get file from stdin
```

The target name is indicated as part of the URL